# How to fill the SafeArray with double datatype values using SafeArrayPutElement

Tags: c++

**I get E_INVALIDARG error**

```
STDMETHODIMP CDocumentController::HasPrivEventCode(double dUserId,double dPosCd,double dPPRCd,SAFEARRAY** pEventCode)
{ 
    // TODO: Add your implementation code here
    long lElements; // number of elements in the array
    long lCount;
    HRESULT lResult; // return code for OLE functions
    double *pArrayElements; // pointer to the elements of the array

    // checking if it is a one-dimensional array
    if ( (*pEventCode)->cDims != 1 ) return(E_FAIL);

    // checking if it is an array of double
    if ( (*pEventCode)->cbElements != 8 ) return(E_FAIL);

    // how many elements are there in the array
    lElements=(*pEventCode)->rgsabound[0].cElements;

    // locking the array before using its elements
    lResult=SafeArrayLock(*pEventCode);
    if (lResult != S_OK) return(E_FAIL);

    // using the array
    pArrayElements=(double*) (*pEventCode)->pvData;

    CMap<double,double,bool,bool> mapEventCds;

    for (lCount=0; lCount<lElements; lCount++) 
    { 
        double lVal = pArrayElements[lCount]; 
        mapEventCds.SetAt(lVal, false); 
    } 
    CheckPrivViewResultEventCds(dUserId, dPosCd, dPPRCd, mapEventCds); 

    long iEventCdIdx(0);
    double          dEventCd(0.0); 
    bool            bPriv(false); 
    POSITION        pos(mapEventCds.GetStartPosition()); 
    INT_PTR             nEventCnt(mapEventCds.GetCount()); 
    double* arrEventCdsWithPriv = new double[nEventCnt];
    VARIANT vt;

    //(*pEventCode)->pvData = NULL;

    lResult=SafeArrayUnlock(*pEventCode); 
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayDestroyData(*pEventCode);

    for(INT_PTR count(0); count < nEventCnt; ++count) 
    { 
        mapEventCds.GetNextAssoc(pos, dEventCd, bPriv); 

        if (bPriv) 
        {   
            vt.vt = VT_R8;
            vt.dblVal = dEventCd;
            hr = SafeArrayPutElement(*pEventCode, &iEventCdIdx, &dEventCd);
            iEventCdIdx++;
        }   
    }
    // Empty the CMap 
    mapEventCds.RemoveAll(); 
    // releasing the array 
    lResult=SafeArrayUnlock(*pEventCode); 

    return S_OK;

}
```

`*pEventCode` is my safearray... `dEventCd` is the 'double' value...I want to insert the `dEventCd` values to my `*pEventCode` safearray one by one when (`bPriv`) is true... Please help

Comment: So what language is it??? You've got it tagged with 4 different languages

Comment: C++..I thought the other language experts can also answer this question.

Comment: Guruparasad, that's not how SO works. Tags are there to give extra information that is pertinent to your question. If the question really does not depend on a language, then tag it as "language-agnostic". But in your case it is very important to know what language it is. Besides, "other language experts" do look at questions tagged outside their primary language so you needn't worry. Rather get the question well formed and people will answer

Comment: Looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891261.aspx), E_INVALIDARG means "One of the arguments is invalid." You haven't shown how you created any of the 3 arguments to the function, so we are in the dark as much as you as to why you're getting the error. Show how you declared `pEventCode` `iEventCdIdx` and `dEventCd`

Comment: Please find the full code. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. I'm sending an array of doubles from VB to C++ and then returning it back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the APIs you are using. However, I was able to throw together this little test app which creates a `SAFEARRAY`, puts the value of 2 into the first index, and then retrieves that value successfully. You'll see in the code below that there is a commented out section which includes a call to `SafeArrayDestroyData`. When that code is commented out, the app works; however, when you uncomment the code, suddenly the call to `SafeArrayPutElement` fails with `E_INVALIDARG`. I believe this is your problem. Don't call this method before putting elements into the `SAFEARRAY`

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <OaIdl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
    rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
    rgsabound[0].cElements = 1;

    SAFEARRAY FAR* psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, rgsabound);

    if (psa == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not create safe array";

        return 0;
    }

    auto hr = SafeArrayLock(psa);
    _com_error lockErr(hr);
    printf(lockErr.ErrorMessage());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    hr = SafeArrayUnlock(psa);
    _com_error unlockErr(hr);
    printf(unlockErr.ErrorMessage());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //This block is causing the trouble!
    /*
    hr = SafeArrayDestroyData(psa);
    _com_error destroyErr(hr);
    printf(destroyErr.ErrorMessage());
    std::cout << std::endl;
    */

    LONG  rgIndex = 0;
    double d = 2.0;

    hr = SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &rgIndex, &d);

    _com_error putErr(hr);
    printf(putErr.ErrorMessage());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (hr == S_OK) {
        double out = 0;
        hr = SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &rgIndex, &out);

        _com_error getErr(hr);
        printf(putErr.ErrorMessage());
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "the value of the element retrieved was: " << out;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```